# redirected cout -> std::stringstream, not seeing EOL

Tags: c++, redirect, stringstream, cout

I've read a bunch of posts regarding redirecting std::cout to stringstreams, but I'm having problem reading the redirected string.

```
std::stringstream redirectStream;
std::cout.rdbuf( redirectStream.rdbuf() );

std::cout << "Hello1\n";
std::cout << "Hello2\n";

while(std::getline(redirectStream, str))
{
  // This does not work - as the contents of redirectStream 
  // do not include the '\n' - I only see "Hello1Hello2"
}
```

I need to pick out the new lines within the initial output - can anyone enlighten me as to how to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: For your information, this works on my machine. (Visual C++ 2008)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works fine for me:
Note: the std::getline() reads the line (but not the '\n' character, the line terminator is thrown away after each line is read). But the loop will be entered once for each line.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::stringstream   redirectStream;
    std::streambuf*     oldbuf  = std::cout.rdbuf( redirectStream.rdbuf() );

    std::cout << "Hello1\n";
    std::cout << "Hello2\n";

    std::string str;
    while(std::getline(redirectStream, str))
    {
        fprintf(stdout,"Line: %s\n",str.c_str());
        // loop enter once for each line.
        // Note: str does not include the '\n' character.
    }

    // In real life use RAII to do this. Simplified here for code clarity.
    std::cout.rdbuf(oldbuf);
}
```

Note: you **need** to put the old stream-buffer back in std::cout. Once the stringstream 'redirectStream' goes out of scope its buffer will be destroyed leaving std::cout pointing at an invalid stream-buffer. Since std::cout lives longer than 'redirectStream' you need to make sure that std::cout does not access an invalid object. Thus the easiest solution is to put back the old buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response. I can kind of see what I've done wrong. Because I stripped out a lot of code to simplify my issue, yes I did actually post a working version! It seems my actual logic was the problem:

```
// Basically... 
std::string str; 
std::stringstream redirectstream; 
// perform the redirection... 
// ... 

while (!done)
{ 
  while(std::getline(redirectStream, str)) 
  { 
    // stuff... 
  } 
  std::cout << "Hello1\n"; 
  std::cout << "Hello2\n"; 
}
```

It appears that the getline() function no longer appears to be valid in this situation. Can you please explain this?

I realize this is a completely different problem now and I apologize for misleading with a bad initial post.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The answer section is for *answers* to the question, not for responses to other answers, or for follow-up questions. To respond to an answer, use the "comment" section below each answer. (The minimum reputation is waived when commenting on your own question page.) I have voted to close this question as "no longer relevant" since you admit that what you posted wasn't really a problem. I advise you to start over and post a *new* question with what you've written in this "answer." (There are answers already, so *editing* the question will just confuse things.)